# How to color Ada procedure/function calls in GNAT GPS

Tags: editor, ada, gnat-gps

Is there a way to color the calling Ada procedures or functions in Gnat GPS IDE?
Is there any custom solution to this?
Check the comment in the following code to see what I mean:

```ada
package body Pkg is

   function Get_Amount (a : b) return Integer is
   begin
      return 0;
   end Get_Amount;

   procedure Print_Owing is
   begin
      Get_Amount (x); --This call here shall be colored if possible but its not.
   end Print_Owing;

end Pkg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the name, try "`Name` is called by" menu item.

Comment: Well thats not what I mean... It should be marked/colored as, for example, the data types.

Comment: Are you asking if you can get GNAT GPS to colour the identifiers in procedure calls with a unique colour?  (I haven't tried, but you could check out the Ada editor settings in GNAT GPS.  There might be something useful.)

Answer (score 0):

The coloration of procedures and functions is not supported.
Even for types, you'll notice that they are only colored when they appear in a declaration or a signature:

```ada
declare:
    a : Some_type; -- colored
    b : Some_Type; -- colored
begin
    a := Some_Type'("42"); -- not colored
    b := Sometype(a);      -- not colored
end
```

In order to be able to identify that something is a function or a procedure, you would have keep track of the whole project semantics in order to color any file.

Comment: Well thats the point of the question. How to bypass or modify something so that it can work the same way as for example intellij etc